# Semantic MediaWiki Get page links?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I have a page set up as a disambiguation page inside of Category:Disambiguations that looks like this:

```
'''Sword''' may refer to one of the following:

* {{Link|Item|Blue Sword}}
* {{Link|Item|Yellow Sword}}
* {{Link|Item|Green Sword}}
```

Is there a way I can use the '#ask' function to get all of the links on that page? This page has no properties on it...

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine the `{{Link}}` template to include `[[Links to::{{{2}}}]]` and declare `Property:Links to` of the type page. Then you will be able to query the links with `{{#show:Sword|Links to}}` or `{{#ask:[[-Links to::Sword]]}}`.